# Adding to a multidimensional array from another array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to figure out how I would do this, basically I want the function to add to the following array:

```
$this->array['key1']['key2']['key3'] = 'value'
```

From a single dimensional array like $this->keys:

```
Array
(
    [0] => key1
    [1] => key2
    [2] => key3
)
```

My function would be:

```
function addToArray($value) {
 $this->array = ...
}
```

I have had a few ideas of using `foreach $this->keys` or for but I don't know how I would preserve the existing array while adding new values onto it.

$keys is maintained in a separate function

For example:

```
foreach ($this->keys as $key) {
  $array = $this->array[$key]
}
$array = $value;
```

But this would create a new single dimensional array and not add to the multidimensional $this->array.  Maybe I am just not thinking correctly.

Comment: Something like this: http://3v4l.org/DpQMq

Comment: @Passerby I see you beat me to it. Post yours as an answer and I'll take mine down.

Comment: Thank you both, unfortunately, it doesn't work if the array exists with other values.  For example, adding a `$this->array['key1'] = 'value1';` before the function breaks it.  Error: Cannot create references to/from string offsets nor overloaded objects

Comment: Well, that's not exactly a multidimensional array is it...

Comment: Lol, yes, I guess you're right.  Guess it is time for bed for me, obviously I'm not thinking correctly.  Thank you for the code though, it does work now that I'm using it correctly.

Comment: @Grexis I'm good, was just posting a quick comment before lunch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like the following:

```
function addToArray($value){
    $tempArray = &$this->array;
    foreach($this->keys as $key){
        $tempArray = &$tempArray[$key];
    }
    $tempArray = $value;
}
```